# Using OR with Selenium.Click - is this possible?

Tags: selenium

There is an image and a link on this webpage. Clicking on either of them does the same job. I was wondering if there is an option of including OR in Selenium.Click. Something like:

```
Selenium.Click("image") OR Selenium.Click("link");
```

Comment: why do you need an OR condition? To click on the element that loads first?

Comment: Just in case it din't find the image, it could click on the link. Vice versa

Comment: @Maya Tests should be deterministic!

Comment: @Tnem There could be realtime scenarios where the data could by dynamic. In such cases wouldn't this be necessary. I use a customized OR condition for AJAX elements in my tests since I wont be able to predetermine whether a particular AJAX popup will be displayed or not. It will popup depending upon on the product.

Comment: @A.J That is no reason, your tests should know whether the popup is going to appear or not, you should test specific products which will force the popup to appear and another tests that tests products which don't make the popup appear.

Comment: @Tnem yes, that would be the "ideal" way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium doesn't offer OR condition. If the requirement is to click on either of the locators depending on which one is available, then you can easily create a custom method

This is written in JAVA, you can change it to your programming language

```
public void ClickOnAvailableLocator(String locator1, String locator2)
{
if(selenium.isVisible(locator1)
 selenium.Click(locator1);
else
 selenium.Click(locator2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, if you need to test both routes I would suggest two tests.